# Why can't I connect to my Amazon S3 storage with two of my three clients?

Tags: connection, amazon-s3, cyberduck, panic-transmit

I use [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/), [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/), and [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/), all of which support connecting to Amazon S3. But for some reason, I can only connect to my S3 storage successfully in Transmit; Cyberduck and Espresso both fail with generic errors like "login failed."

I know that I have the correct access key ID and secret access key because, as I said, I have no problem connecting in Transmit. I even imported my Transmit bookmark directly into Cyberduck, and yet I still can't connect through it.

Any ideas? I've gone back and forth comparing Transmit's settings to Cyberduck and Espresso and I can't find anything that would explain the discrepancy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the assumption that you have created an IAM user with a dedicated policy it might miss the s3:ListAllMyBuckets action. If so, you can browse a single bucket in Cyberduck by connecting to `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com` instead of the default S3 hostname. Refer to http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#Externalbuckets.